# QGIS Layer Attribute Table Field Calculator Default Values

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, layers

QGIS 2.18.9
In a large project, I have more than 50 layers to which I want to add a new real number field.  The default values which are displayed in Field Calculator for field type, size and precision are Integer, 10 and 0 respectively.  To change these for each individual layer, I seem to have to enter Decimal Number, 6 and 2 every time which is very time-consuming. Is there a way I can change the default values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Add field to attributes table](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_table_tools/addfieldtoattributestable.html) tool either in patch process or using python pyqgis. The following small code will add a new field of Type real, length of 6, and precision of 2:

```
import processing
layers = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()
for layer in layers:
    processing.runalg('qgis:addfieldtoattributestable', layer, "TestField",1,6,2, r"C:\Path\To\Output\Folder\\"+layer.name())
```

1. First load all the shapefiles that you want to add a new field for them in QGIS using `add feature`
2. Click on Open `Python Console` from the `Plugins toolbar`
3. Click on `Show editor`, as shown below:

[image]

4. Paste the above code, but before running the code, you need to
   change the following:

   - Replace "TestField" with a new field name
   - Define the output path for the newly created shapefile